# Appcelerator studio not launching

Tags: appcelerator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Qf4.png)I updated my mac os to ios11 beta and tried launching the appcelerator studio but it is throwing a warning symbol and not launching.[era](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLwbb.png)

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am unable to launch Appcelerator studio from the osx dock. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: it seems that for ios11 the appcelerator haven't released any update, so I am using atom studio.

Comment: I am using Atom now too